# Send empty string with SoapClient

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I am integrating a website with a SOAP API.
But I am facing an issue when I need to send an empty string (not a null value) as I do with SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Datos_Articulo soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <ID xsi:type="xsd:string"></ID>
         <IP xsi:type="xsd:string">0</IP>
         <CodS xsi:type="xsd:string">TA8094BK</CodS>
         <Nombre_Carrito xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Nombre_Carrito>
         <TablaSinTags xsi:type="xsd:boolean">?</TablaSinTags>
      </urn:Datos_Articulo>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

But when doing this and inspecting the request with $client->__getLastRequest() method, it always sends this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Datos_Articulo>
        <ID xsi:type="xsd:string">Array</ID>
        <IP xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CodS xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Nombre_Carrito xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TablaSinTags xsi:nil="true"/>
    </ns1:Datos_Articulo>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

This is how My parameters are prepared before sending them:

```
$params = array(
"ID" => "",
"CodS" => $code,
"IP" => '0',
'TablaSinTags' => false
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The error was when calling the __soapCall method, I was passing as argument:
array($params) instead of only $params (since $params is already an array).
I double checked the arguments needed at: https://www.php.net/manual/es/soapclient.soapcall.php